# How to deploy my MANTIS web application on the server of the local network in our company

Tags: iis, web-applications, web-deployment, windows-server-2012, mantis

I have a web application named MANTIS (Open source) and after configuring it, i want to deploy it in our local network in the company.

i used XAMPP on the server and the application is accessible in the server only and it is not accesible from any other computer from the network.

When i put the adress http://192.168.10.150:8080/mantis from any other computer connected to the same network, it shows me an error message.

can anyone help me to make it accessible from any computer connected to the netword ?

we are using

> WINDOWS SERVER 2012 R2
>
> IIS